# Payment gateway not showing up in Opencart checkout page

Tags: e-commerce, payment-gateway, opencart

I have created a custom payment gateway module by following paypal standard module and it shows up fine in checkout page while I tested it in localhost. But in live site after installing and enabling it from the module page It doesn't show up anymore.  then I tried installing and enabling paypal standard module too and found that it is not showing up too.  On the other hand bank transfer module shows up just fine after installing. I am out of ideas exactly why this is happening. Any insights on this issue will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Things I have checked so far:

1. File permission - found OK
2. database - found all necessary values added and updated after installing
3. no error found in checkout page. I used firebug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I found the solution myself. It was a default currency issue. If you use a currency that is not supported by paypal, the option in the checkout page wont simply show up. As I created the new module following pp_standard payment gateway, it was inheriting the same logic and was not showing up. Hope it helps someone in future and saves a good amount of time wasted. Cheers!

Comment: For my demo store i used US as store country, USD as currency and US and customer country and enabled Paypal standard with my paypal account and choose sandbox mode in opencart paypal payment settings. Still only COD is visible in checkout. I couldnt find the issue.